# How to dismiss a modalCtrl from app.component.ts in Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi I am trying to dismiss a modalctrl from app.component.ts using this.viewCtrl.dismiss(); in Ionic3 , but getting below error

```
No provider for ViewController!
```

Is there any workaround for dismissing modalctrl from app.component.ts

```
/****app.component.ts***/
    method(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();//error
       const params = {
          networkStatus: status,
        };
        this.modalCtrl
          .create(NetworkComponent, params, {
            showBackdrop: false,
            enableBackdropDismiss: false,
          })
          .present();
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you share more of your code? like include a component from which you are trying to dismiss (is that app.component?) and where and how such modal gets presented? from another component?

Comment: yes this is app.component...

Comment: I am trying open NetworkComponent from app.component modalCtrl for multiple conditions,  but I want to dismiss the same before open next one